# I'm confused why this line show me the error in PC but Mac can work with it

Tags: c++, fstream

On `outfile = fstream(filename);` There shows me `private 'ios_base::operator=(const ios_base&)' is inaccessible`, I don't know how to solve it, I'm using clion to compile it, but for Mac, no problem on it

```
class ErrorHandler{
private:

    std::fstream outfile;

public:
    ErrorHandler(char const filename[]) {

        outfile = fstream(filename);

        outfile << filename << " opened"  << endl;
    }

    ~ErrorHandler(){

    }

    void warn(char const message[]){

        cout << message << endl;

        outfile << message << endl;

    }


    void terminate(char const message[]){

        cout << message << endl;

        outfile << message << endl;

        exit(1);

    }
};

int main() {

    ErrorHandler h("log.txt");

    h.warn("Error 10: this is your first warning");
    h.warn("Error 20: I warned you");
    h.terminate("Error 30:  Told you so.");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Properly format your code as code. It's a single click of a button.

Comment: Are you compiling on PC under at least C++11?

Comment: The last edit to this post removed the actual error message from the main post and includes it in the code.

Comment: I'm not sure it's C++11 above or not, I just learned C++, so could you help me how I should know it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is that you can't assign one `fstream` to another, which is exactly what is happening when you assign it.

You've a few options, but the easiest is to declare `outfile` as an `std::fstream*`, and then in your constructor:

```
outfile = new fstream(filename);
```

Remember to delete it in your destructor.

Comment: There really is no need for dynamic allocation, or even pointers here.

Comment: Thank you for answering my problem, but my friend use Mac to copy down exactly same coding as mine, there's no any errors, I don't know why it's error on PC.  This coding it given by my professor, he runs is fine as well

Comment: @user6482243 It isn't valid C++. I can't imagine how your friend can get it to compile, but maybe their code is different.

Comment: Let me double check the problems again, maybe something wrong on it, thank you so much tho

Comment: When I delete that error statement, It can work and run without any error,  Is that legal?